# Display a ul list bullet on the side of a div

Tags: html, css

I have a list of divs with paragraphs inside each element. I would like to treat it as an unordered list and display a custom bullet on the left side of each div. However, I get the bullet on top of the divs.

[The fiddle](http://jsbin.com/mucanexatu/edit?html,css,output) shows my problem and what I would like to see.

If this is not possible to achieve with this html structure, I would be glad to hear some other suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this with absolute positioning, but I generally prefer to avoid positioning that if at all possible.

Ultimately, I just set the div to indent the same as the straight li tag, and then floated the +.

```css
ul {
  width: 300px;
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  margin: 40px;
  padding-left: 0px;
}

li > div { margin-left: 40px;}

li:before {
  content: "+";
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding-right: 30px;
}
```

```html
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div>
        <p>This is out of place</p>
        <span>some other thing that wants to be here</span>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>This works as intended</li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: As I still do not fully understand how absolute/relative positioning works together, I tend to agree. This is a very intuitive way, I am going to use it, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Used `position:absolute` for that:

```css
ul {
  width: 300px;
  list-style: none;
  padding:0;
}

li {
  margin:0 0 40px;
  padding-left: 30px;  
  position:relative;
}

li:before {
  content: "+";
  padding-right: 30px;
  display:inline-block;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
      <div>
        <p>This is out of place</p>
        <span>some other thing that wants to be here</span>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>This works as intended some other thing that wants to be here</li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: It was pleasure to help you out! :)

Answer (score 2):

I usually use the css hack like below without using any `<ul>` or `<ol>` only divs:

```
display: list-item;
list-style-type: circle;
```

```css
div.list-div {
  display: list-item;
  margin-left: 1.3em;
  list-style-type: circle;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="list-div">
  <p>This is out of place</p>
  <span>some other thing that wants to be here</span>
</div>

<div class="list-div">
  <p>This is out of place</p>
  <span>some other thing that wants to be here</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it compatible with older browsers?

Comment: @Simoroshka, Visit bootstrap to know more about browser compatibility. here http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support-ie-compatibility-modes

Comment: Also, how about the custom list-type?

Comment: @Simoroshka, you can see it in here for custom `list-style-type` http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_list-style-type.asp

Comment: My point is, I need to use a unicode character that is not included in list-style-type

Comment: `float left` like other answer will comes in rescue :)

Answer (score 1):

Add a `float: left;` to you `li:before` css declaration.   The `:before` selector inserts before the content of the tag, not before the tag. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_before.asp.   If you inspect the element with a browser's developer tools you will see the "+" inside the `<li>` tags.

```
li:before {
  content: "+";
  padding-right: 30px;
  float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Scott, that float is a better option and other methods tend to break layouts with positioning.

I want to more so show why `li:before` does place it above and that is because technically you want it, in your case, before the paragraph and so `p:before` would have worked as below shows.

```css
ul {
  width: 600px;
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  margin: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
}

li > div { margin-left: 0px;}

p:before {
  content: "+";
  margin-left: -18px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div>
        <p>I am a paragraph</p>
        <span>That is why p:before works and not li:before</span>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>This works as intended</li>
  </ul>
```